# A generic error occurred in GDI+ while loading

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, gdi+

im receiving "A generic error occurred in GDI+" while loading an image FromFile().
this happens on a few images.

I tried numerous of things to fix this error, but to no avail.

via google i found out a lot of people having this issue when they save the file. i get it when i try to load it.

all i do is:

> image =
>   System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\pic.jpeg");

anyone fixed this error when loading an image from file?

Comment: you probably need to get the source symbols http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx and find out exactly which  generic error it really is. I had this when the image format is unsupported (certain versions of TIFF)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're encountering is that the file is already open. Maybe you opened it by putting it into a `PictureBox`, or you opened it already?
You should see if its opened by using [Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml). 
I got this error when having the file open in a `Bitmap` already. Be sure to `Dispose` every Bitmap object after using it.

Comment: im not displaying the images. im only comparing them to each other and relocate one picture if they are identical. in my finally block i dispose the image object and call GC.Collect(). also the file is not already opened anywhere. this happens right at computer startup and application startup.